# restrict a date picker with another date picker using asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have two date pickers in my page .the first date picker should be enabled dates from day before today means(example today is 19/Nov/2016 then the first date picker  values enable from 17/Nov/2016)and the second date picker should be enabled of week days from the first date picker selected value(means if I select 18/Nov/2016 then my second date picker should be avail up to 25/Nov/2016 only not beyond that value and not accept that value)
Here my code is

```
    <html>
    <head>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#txtFrom").datepicker({
                    minDate:0
                });
                var dates = $("#txtFrom,#txtTo").datepicker({
                    minDate: '0',
                    maxDate: '+7D',
                    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                        var option = this.id == "txtFrom" ? "minDate" :maxDate",
                        instance = $(this).data("datepicker"),
                        date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings);
                        dates.not(this).datepicker("option", option, date);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .ui-datepicker {
                font-size: 8pt !important;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div class="demo">
                <label for="from">From</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtFrom" runat="server" />
                <label for="to">to</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTo" runat="server" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Here I'm not exactly getting output what I want .kindly help me to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the JQuery datepicker documentation - 
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/

What you're looking for is the "beforeShow" callback and the "minDate" property.